# How to retrieve the 64-bit address for a specific kernel object from a wow64 process

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to obtain the 64-bit address of a kernel object from within a 32-bit WOW64 process?

For instance, I want to obtain the 64-bit kernel address for a process with a given pid. This value would be the "UniqueProcessKey" for a Kernel Logger process event.

I can obtain the 32-bit address by using NtDll:

```
NtQuerySystemInformation

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE {
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE;
```

But I need the 64-bit address.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a 64 bit process

Comment: I could use a 64 bit process with SendMessage or something , however I just want to know if its possible from within a single wow64 process

Comment: A 32-bit process has no concept of 64-bit addresses, and as such, all API functions return the 32-bit values that are useful in a 32-bit process. I'd suggest porting the application to 64-bit.

Comment: Hypothetically, if you **could* get the 64-bit address of the object, what would you do with it inside of a 32-bit process?

Comment: With the address of the kernel objects, I would match them to "Key" objects, to determine the full registry path during Kernel Logging of the registry. Similar to matching Process Typegroup 1  "UniqueProcessKey."

Answer (score 1):

Well I found my answer.

The premise was that since wow64 is an emulator living within the address space of a 64 bit process, it should be possible to call the 64 bit versions of the Nt... functions. Turns out you can. There are functions like:

```
32-bit:                      64-bit:
NtQuerySystemInformation     NtWow64GetNativeSystemInformation
NtQueryInformationProcess    NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64
```

There is a problem however. NtWow64GetNativeSystemInformation doesn't support the SystemHandleInformation class, at least on Win7. As such I cannot get the addresses.

Regardless, if you need to deal with 64-bit processes in a 32 bit wow process you cant escape from because of some dependency, SO has some other threads worth looking into:

How to get list of GDI handles

Get command line string of 64-bit process from 32-bit process